# Using break command as argument to function

Tags: function, bash-script

What about use so solution?

Functions run in loop (cycle?). In that loop - I have another function wuch also uses loop. When second function get NO answer from user - it send `break 2` to stop loop and proceed main script actions.

Function uses variables wich set in file.

So, is it good idea use variables as parameters for functions?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Is it bad idea - use variables as parametrs for functions?

Comment: Not at all, in fact that is the most common use of functions. You almost always pass variables to a function and not hardcoded values, otherwise functions would not be very useful at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative that might be cleaner is to have `answer` return 0 or return 1, depending on whether the user said `yes` or `no`.  Then test the value of `answer` in the place where you call it, and only do the action if `answer` returned 0.

Based on your earlier script, it would look something like this:

```
while tomcat_running && user_wants_to_stop_tomcat; do
    echo "$tomcat_status_stopping"
    kill $RUN
    sleep 2
done

function tomcat_running() {
    check_tomcat_status
    [ -n "$RUN" ]
}

function user_wants_to_stop_tomcat() {
    answer "WARNING: Tomcat still running. Kill it? "
}

function answer() {
    while true; do
        printf "$1"
        read response
        case $response in
        [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
            return 0
            ;;
        [nN][oO]|[nN])
            return 1
            ;;
        *)
            printf "Please, enter Y(yes) or N(no)!\n"
            ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

Comment: `answer` function used in many places... but - good idea, thanks!